# Git diff-tree always print full commit hash

Tags: git, git-diff-tree

I'd like to get the abbreviated commit hash of `HEAD` using diff-tree, but I've tried all the following, all of which output a full commit hash:

```
git diff-tree --no-patch --abbrev-commit HEAD
git diff-tree --no-patch --abbrev=10 HEAD
git diff-tree --no-patch --format=%h HEAD
git diff-tree --no-patch --pretty=format:%h HEAD
```

I've switched to `git rev-parse --short --verify HEAD` to get what I expected, but I wonder why  diff-tree just won't give me an abbreviated commit hash?

Comment: Why on earth would you use `git diff-tree` at all if the question is what's the SHA of the current commit?

Comment: `git show --format=%h -s @`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure 100% why the `format` is ignored, probably it's mentioned somewhere in the docs. But after looking in the `diff-tree` docs and especially the `--abbrev-commit` [part](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree#Documentation/git-diff-tree.txt---abbrev-commit), adding `--abbrev=n` displays `n` length hash.

```
git diff-tree --no-patch --abbrev-commit --abbrev=10 HEAD
```